# Use IMarkupExtension together with StringFormat

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, translation, markup-extensions

I'm using the [`TranslateExtension`](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UsingResxLocalization/UsingResxLocalization/PagesXaml/TranslateExtension.cs) from Xamarin. Is it possible to add a `StringFormat` to the call?

Currently, I have

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate User}" />
```

but I would need something like this

```
<Label Text="{i18n:Translate User, StringFormat='{0}:'}" />
```

If I do the latter, I get

> Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Cannot assign property "StringFormat": Property does not exists, or is not assignable, or mismatching type between value and property

I know I could add another translation with a colon, but it would be nice to have a different option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a parameter property to TranslateExtension.

My TranslateExtension looks like this. You can take the Parameter parts and add it to the one from the Xamarin sample.

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Text == null)
                return null;

            var culture = new CultureInfo(CultureHelper.CurrentIsoLanguage);

            var result = LocalizationResources.ResourceManager.GetString(Text, culture);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Parameter))
            {
                return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) ? "__TRANSLATE__" : result;
            }

            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result) ? "__TRANSLATE__" : string.Format(result, Parameter);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TinyInsights.TrackErrorAsync(ex);
            return "__TRANSLATE__";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some notations from me: Adding a property seems to work. The Xaml syntax is `<Label Text="{i18n:Translate User, Parameter='{0}:' }"`. Shouldn't it be `string.Format(Parameter, Text)`? And to have the same behavior `Parameter` should be renamed to `StringFormat`.

Comment: Yes, you have right. I misunderstood your question a little bit. Note that I also updated the last row in the try statement to be correct.

Comment: Regarding the [`string.Format()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx) part I think the two parameters need to be swapped.

Comment: Yes, if you want to use it like you want string.Format(StringFormat, translatedText);

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but doing it with the standard extension and just XAML, go like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding YourDynamicValue, StringFormat={i18n:Translate KeyInResources}}"/>
```

Your translation should look something like: `Static text {0}`. Where `{0}` is replaced by the value you bind to.

The problem is that the `Translate` extension just gets your string out of the resources, and doesn't have a `StringFormat` property etc. But you can assign the retrieved resource value to the `StringFormat` of the `Binding`.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have updated the Xamarin sample:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    readonly CultureInfo ci = null;
    const string ResourceId = "UsingResxLocalization.Resx.AppResources";

    static readonly Lazy<ResourceManager> ResMgr = new Lazy<ResourceManager>(() => new ResourceManager(ResourceId, IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TranslateExtension)).Assembly));

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string StringFormat {get;set;}

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS || Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        }
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var translation = ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);
        if (translation == null)
        {
#if DEBUG
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),
                "Text");
#else
            translation = Text; // HACK: returns the key, which GETS DISPLAYED TO THE USER
#endif
        }

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(StringFormat)
             return string.Format(StringFormat, translation);

        return translation;
    }
}
```