# How can I change the language of my app in runtime to "th" (Thai) using MultilingualPlugin [Xamarin on mac]?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile, internationalization

I want to programmatically change the language of my App to "th" (Thai) **in runtime**.  My current code, shown below, is not working.  How can I do this?

First step I created helpers with this code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using Plugin.Multilingual;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace AMIMobile.Helpers
{
    [ContentProperty("Text")]
    public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        const string ResourceId = "AMIMobile.AppResources";

        static readonly Lazy<ResourceManager> resmgr = new Lazy<ResourceManager>(() => new ResourceManager(ResourceId, typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));

        public string Text { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Text == null)
                return "";

            var ci = CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo;

            var translation = resmgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);

            if (translation == null)
            {
#if DEBUG
                throw new ArgumentException( 
                    String.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture      '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),
                    "Text");
#else
                translation = Text; // returns the key, which GETS DISPLAYED TO THE USER
#endif
            }
            return translation;
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I have AppResources with 2 files

- AppResources
- AppResource.th

They contain resources with the same names, but different values.

Then in my view I create xlmns like this :

```
   xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:AMIMobile.Helpers"
```

and binding with this

```
Text="{helpers:Translate Sign In}"
```

The output is English, but I want to show the th (Thai) language, so I put the following code in App.cs

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CrossMultilingual.Current.CurrentCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("th");
     
    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
}
```

But the app does not change to th language.  What am I doing wring?

I want to switch language to th with AppResource.th

Comment: Are you using code from one of the answers from [Use IMarkupExtension together with StringFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51047604/3744182)?  If so, you must give credit as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing.  Please [edit] your question to do so.

Comment: Is `MultilingualPlugin` from https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin?  If so, then the [README](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin#readme) states *THIS PLUGIN IS DECPRECATED - NOT UNDER DEVELOPMENT AND NOT SUPPORTED. This plugin is no longer needed. More information here: https://xamgirl.com/handle-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms-without-any-plugin/*

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MultilingualPlugin, then why are you using a deprecated plugin?  Why not use the approach from https://xamgirl.com/handle-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms-without-any-plugin/?  If using something else, please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve],specifically the plugin you are using.  Thanks!